# cursor should move to missing field in the register form in magento

Tags: javascript, magento, registration

this is code for register.phtml http://pastebin.com/yhz35r9G

it includes fields = "1.first name", "2.last name" , "3.email", "4.password" &

"5.confirm password" and than at the end "submit button"

what i want is if we miss any field in 5 fields and click on "submit button",

than "cursor" should move to "missing field", if 2 fields are missing than cursor should move

to first missing field , than in second missing field.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code (I used jQuery to do this task.)

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="name"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="email"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="pass"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="cpass"/><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

//javascript code
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").submit(function(){
            name = $("#name").val();
            email = $("#email").val();
            pass = $("#pass").val();
            cpass = $("#cpass").val();
            if(name == "" || name == null){
                $("#name").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(email == "" || email == null){
                $("#email").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(pass == "" || pass == null){
                $("#name").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(cpass == "" || cpass == null){
                $("#cpass").focus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/8kzj1t31/